# Pathogenesis of Chronic Venous Congestion in Lungs?

Tags: pathogenesis, lungs, congestion

I am thinking how CVC in lungs lead to the left-sided heart failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CVC lead to Pulmonary congestion and edema.
They produce heavy, wet lungs.

Pulmonary changes include

1. perivascular and interstitial edema, particularly in the interlobular septa;
2. progessive edematous widening of alveolar septa; and
3. accumulation of edema fluid in alveolar spaces which contain Hemosiderin and microhemorrhages

Now, the progression of the disease to heart should be discussed.
I am not sure if hemosiderin can go directly from lungs to heart or if it has to travel through circulation and then to left-side of lung.